# accessing object after $http.get

Tags: angularjs

Data after `$http.get`

Hi!

Please help me to take the fields and assign to new arrays. 
Below is my angular codes:

```
app.directive("auto1", [ '$http', function( $http) {

    data = $http.get("./php/fetchElement.php").then(function (response) {
      return response.data.records;       
    });

        console.log(data);

   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function() {

        $('#auto1').autocomplete({source:[states]})     
   }
};
}]);
```

It no problem when i use ngrepet in HTML but in js... :((.

Comment: can you put more details ..what is that you want to do with data drom http.get?

Comment: I am sorry for my not clear question. the console.log(data) is as below 
$$state: Object
status: 1
value: Array[11]
0: Object
Code: "100000"
Name: "My Name"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
length: 11
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: d
.

Comment: data contain an array of 11 objects as shown, I want to access the value of every object or take all Field "Name", "Code" to assign to single direction Arrays within javascript.

Thank for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your data variable  at  the console.log is a promis ($http.get returns a promise). $scope variables will be set to returned value once the promise is resolved.

```
    app.directive("auto1", [ '$http', function( $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            data: '=auto1',
            autoUrl: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            $http.get(scope.autoUrl).then(function (response) {
                scope.data=response.data.records;       
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

At your HTML:

```
<ul auto1="data" auto-url="./php/fetchElement.php"><li ng-repeat="item in data">{{data.property}}</li><ul>
```